# Is this C# 'hack' a bad idea?

Tags: c#, c++, generics

As C# doesn't have generic specialisation like C++ template specialisation and I wanted a way to be able to do it, I came up with a little hack that goes a bit like this:

```
    public sealed class Specialisation<T> 
    { 
        private Specialisation() { }
        private static Specialisation<T> instance = new Specialisation<T>();
        public static Specialisation<T> Instance { get { return instance; } }
    }
    public interface ISpecialisable<T>
    {
        T SpecialisedMethod(Specialisation<T> t);
    }
    public class Specialised : ISpecialisable<int>, ISpecialisable<float>
    {
        public double Value;
        public int SpecialisedMethod(Specialisation<int> t) { return (int)Value; }
        public float SpecialisedMethod(Specialisation<float> t) { return (float)Value; }
    }
    public static class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
           Specialised s = new Specialised();
           s.Value = 12.3456789;
           Console.WriteLine(s.SpecialisedMethod(Specialisation<int>.Instance));
           Console.WriteLine(s.SpecialisedMethod(Specialisation<float>.Instance));
           Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

Other than this not being the 'right way' to do things and being a complete mistreatment of the method overloading system, are there any possible side effects that could happen as a result of this horrible hack?

EDIT:

An applied example of specialisation in such a manner:

```
    // assume Specialisation is unchanged
    public interface IConvertible<T> // Not to be confused with System.IConvertible
    {
        T Convert(Specialisation<T> t);
    }
    public class ConvertMe : IConvertible<int>, IConvertible<float>
    {
        public double Value;
        public int Convert(Specialisation<int> t) { return (int)Value; }
        public float Convert(Specialisation<float> t) { return (float)Value; }
    }
    public static class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
           ConvertMe c = new ConvertMe();
           c.Value = 12.3456789;
           Console.WriteLine(c.Convert(Specialisation<int>.Instance));
           Console.WriteLine(c.Convert(Specialisation<float>.Instance));
           Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

EDIT:
Another example I just thought of as an extension of/alternative to the `IConvertible<T>` example. This technique allows the normal generic method syntax to be used externally, whilst allowing the class developer to internally define specialisations.

```
public interface IConvertible<T>
{
    T Convert(Specialisation<T> t);
    T Convert<T>();
}
// assume Specialisation<T> is unchanged
public class ConvertMe : IConvertible<int>, IConvertible<float>
{
    public double Value;
    int IConvertible<int>.Convert(Specialisation<int> t) { return (int)Value; }
    float IConvertible<float>.Convert(Specialisation<float> t) { return (float)Value; }
    public T Convert<T>() { return ((IConvertible<T>)this).Convert(Specialisation<T>.Instance); }
}
public static class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        ConvertMe c = new ConvertMe();
        c.Value = 12.3456789;
        Console.WriteLine(c.Convert<int>());
        Console.WriteLine(c.Convert<float>());
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

This use of specialisation could be generalised to other applications in order to provide specialised behaviour. I won't add any more examples as the ones provided are long enough as it is, and I'm sure everyone here has the skill and imagination to find other applications of this pattern.

Comment: " are there any possible side effects that could happen as a result of this horrible hack?"    Do you mean like unemployment?

Comment: I'm not employed anyway.

Comment: Could you explain why would you want to do this? How is your code better than `s.SpecialisedMethodForInt()`?

Comment: I find it pretty "special"... what is it used for? Why the `static` stuff?

Comment: @svick By doing it this way, ISpecialisable only needs to be declared once and it can be used for any new classes or interfaces, thus it is more extensible than just creating new interfaces each time you come up with a new type to specialise to.

Comment: @lol.upvote If the Specialisation class could be created dynamically then people would end up creating a new Specialisation every time they wanted to use a SpecialisedMethod, which would be wasteful as the object would end up being created and not really used, which is wasteful of time and memory. By using the Singleton pattern only one instance is ever made, thus memory is saved by only having one instance and time is saved by not having to waste time allocating heap space for a 'dummy' instance.

Comment: Just a thought - maybe `interface IConvertible<T> { T Convert(T targetType); }` could be used? There could be some issues with implicit conversions (int->long etc.) though. This has added value of enabling you to use anonymous types. Or you could provide implicit conversion from `targetType` to `Specialisation` enabling you to keep the original definition but much shorter usage.

Comment: @Knaģis It could, but then you'd end up having to create an instance of T on the fly or cache an instance to use with the specialised function, which is why I decided to opt for the singleton pattern. I like the idea of the implicit conversion, but to me that rings out as an extra step of unnecessary complexity. If `ISpecialisable` could force the implementer to define an explicit cast, that might be one solution from the conversion aspect, but only in the conversion situation.

Comment: @Knaģis So, to convert to `int` you would write `Convert(0)`? That seems really confusing to me. And I don't think it allows you to use anonymous types, how would you create a class that implements `IConvertible<anonymous type>`?

Comment: Please, don't edit your question with completely new code, it invalidates the existing answers. See [this meta question for more details](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1763/2041).

Comment: @svick Should I ask a new question and risk [duplicate question] or make the existing one even longer and risk complaints about it being to long?

Comment: @Pharap You should ask a new question. It's okay to do that and it's not considered a duplicate question. See also [How to post a follow-up question?](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1065/2041)

Comment: @svick Thank you, I will consider posting a follow up. To be safe though I may formulate another example so it's definitely bringing something new to the table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that there any nasty hidden downsides to it. As you noted C# doesn't have real specialisations and the only way to have the same method just differing by return type is the way you chose - so if that's what you need then that's what you have to do.

Only note is that I'd consider adding a non-generic class like this

```
public static class Specialisation
{
    public static Specialisation<T> For<T>()
    {
        return Specialisation<T>.Instance;
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
Specialised s = new Specialised();
s.Value = 12.3456789;
Console.WriteLine(s.SpecialisedMethod(Specialisation.For<int>()));
Console.WriteLine(s.SpecialisedMethod(Specialisation.For<float>()));
Console.ReadKey();
```

which reads a tiny bit nicer.

You can hide the generic class as internal in your assembly and expose an `ISpecialisation` interface if you don't want users of your system exposed to the generic and non-generic versions.

Comment: I like the idea of the non-generic class. I'm partly against the `ISpecialisation` purely because other people can derive from it, which partly defeats the point of offering singletons to use as the generic parameters, but it does offer the user more flexibility. Flexibility to do what exactly I don't know, but flexibility nonetheless.

Answer (score 6):

First of all, I would question the need for such interface. It makes sense for a type to hold a value, but I think it doesn't make much sense for a type to decide to what types to convert that value, or how.

Second, if you really do need this, then I would prefer each target type to have a separate method, like `ConvertToInt()` (or `ConvertToInt32()` if you follow the naming guidelines).

You don't necessarily need an interface for this, but even if you do, you're exchanging a small inconvenience in implementation (having to write few very simple interfaces with some repetition) for a big inconvenience in usage (having to write that `Specialisation<int>.Instance` every time and making the code less readable). So, I think using this approach is worth it even with interfaces.

Third, if you really do need this and you want to take advantage of generics, you could use explicit interface implementation and casting to decide to what type to convert. Something like:

```
public interface IConvertible<T>
{
    T Convert();
}

public sealed class ConvertMe : IConvertible<int>, IConvertible<float>
{
    public double Value;
    int IConvertible<int>.Convert() { return (int)Value; }
    float IConvertible<float>.Convert() { return (float)Value; }
}

public static class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
       ConvertMe c = new ConvertMe();
       c.Value = 12.3456789;
       Console.WriteLine(((IConvertible<int>)c).Convert());
       Console.WriteLine(((IConvertible<float>)c).Convert());
    }
}
```

This results in code that is shorter and more readable (I think) than your version.

One issue with it is that if you don't make `ConvertMe` `sealed`, trying to convert to an unsupported type becomes a runtime exception, instead of a compile-time error.

Comment: Personally I don't like the `ConvertToType` naming style because it produces multiple functions with the same purpose that semantically differ only in type (which is what the whole point of specialisation is - being able to define different behaviours dependent on type alone). The casting to an interface variation is definitely useful; personally I find it harder to read though because of the additional brackets it introduces. The point about making `ConvertMe` `sealed` is also valid, though it's not too bad considering that this is a hack - you'd expect limitations like that.